# How to ensure that `self.skipWaiting()` works while allowing POST requests in service worker's fetch event

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I've noticed that my service worker doesn't respond to `self.skipWaiting()` when there are still tasks to be run.

In my service worker's `fetch` event, I see various Firebase polls that use HTTP POST requests.

If I handle these requests in the service worker like so:

```js
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  if (event.request.method === "POST") {
    return event.respondWith(new Response(null, {status: 444}))
  }

  ...
})
```

Then `self.skipWaiting()` always works as expected.

However, if I do the following:

```js
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  if (event.request.method === "POST") {
    return event.respondWith(fetch(event.request))
  }

  ...
})
```

Then `self.skipWaiting()` seems to have no effect. In Chrome's devtools, the new service worker still isn't active (and also clicking on the blue `skipWaiting` link also has no effect). [image: Chrome devtools screenshot showing the new service worker as waiting to activate]

As a result, it seems that I have to choose between ensuring that `self.skipWaiting()` works, and allowing Firebase's polling requests, but not both. Is there a way get `self.skipWaiting()` to work while still allowing Firebase's polling requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see from your code *where* you're calling `self.skipWaiting()`, but the [main thing to know about that function](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-global-scope-skipwaiting) is that it "flips" a flag and attempts to activate the `waiting` service worker. I'm not sure which part of that sequence is not working as expected, and I'm also not sure if you're describing something that happens just in Chrome or in other browsers as well. If you're seeing unexpected behavior just in Chrome, [filing a bug](https://crbug.com/new) is probably your best bet.

That being said, in the interest of providing a workaround, I wanted to say that you don't have to call `event.respondWith()` inside of a `fetch` event handler at all. If all your `fetch` handlers complete without any of them calling `fetchEvent.respondWith()`, then the default browser networking behavior will be used instead. So you could restructure your `fetch` handler like the following, and perhaps work around the issue.

```js
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  if (event.request.method === 'POST') {
    return;
  }

  // Your non-POST response logic goes here.
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Jeff! I've also learned a lot from your other Stack Overflow answers and really appreciate all that you do. I will file a bug and link to a GitHub repo, with a video reproducing the issue. In the meantime, simply returning works! Thanks again!

Comment: Filed an issue [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1324445) that references [this minimal code repo](https://github.com/persianturtle/service-worker-issue) that includes a [video overview](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M3HvvVll8T38i2YVGAjaOsovkYyCvGlk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Firefox and Safari seem to be working just fine.